# edit a paragraph with user input using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

This is an edit function like in CRUD system, but the idea is to simplify whereby when the user by using single or double click on an item, it will be turned into a field to directly update the data..

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DNmNE/)

The problem is I can't type anything into the field, I wonder why...

**Html**

```
<li style="list-style:none">click here to edit</li>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('li').click(function(){
   $(this).html("<input id='input' type='text'>");
});

$('#input').blur(function(){
  var newVal = ('#input').val();
      $('li').text('newVal');   
   });
});
```

Comment: jEditable plugin? http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/default.html

Comment: this is a good plugin to do stuff like this.  Have a look to see if it fits your purpose.  http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html

Comment: @tonoslfx He almost has it working, why bloat everything with a plugin when html5 contenteditable would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because a click on the textfield is also a click on the 'li'. Therefore it adds a new textfield when you click on the existing textfield.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DNmNE/5/

And the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li').click(function(){
       input = $("<input id='input' type='text'>").blur(function(){
          $('.editable').removeClass('editable');
          var newVal = $(this).val();
          $('li').text(newVal);   
       });
       if (!$(this).hasClass('editable'))
           $(this).addClass('editable').html(input);
    });
    });
```

I used the .editable class to detect if a textfield is already open.

Comment: Please add also `input = $("<input id='input' type='text' value='"+this.innerHMTL+"'>"). ...` to your code.

Comment: a)input is a variable?

Comment: @Stano It was accepted as the correct answer to the question, and seems to be working fine to me. It does work correctly.

Comment: @Nurul Yes, input is a variable, you need it to bind the blur event and use it later to set HTML content. I just forgot to write 'var' because I'm used to CoffeeScript ;)

Comment: @Parrotmaster Partially, it always creates the empty input element. But [it's easy to fix](http://jsfiddle.net/DNmNE/8/). Ferdinand's answer is great, so of course +1.

Answer (score 1):

Well my amigo, you are appending a new input everytime you click so you need to type real fast (just kidding). But thats the problem. loose the li click function.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but have you considered using the **HTML5** `contenteditable` functionality?

http://html5demos.com/contenteditable

Obviously, it's not going to work in obsolete browsers, but if you're not concerned with that then it will save you a lot of work as your application grows.

Comment: Why is that an issue? Not why *might* it be an issue, but why would it be a problem in @Nurul's example?

Comment: my whole project is almost in jquery, is there anything that is similar to HTML5's contenteditable can be done in jquery? or a custom logic perhaps?

Comment: localstorage is.....local. Only the person editing it can see it, which I doubt is what he wants. Plus it easily gets thrown away by a simple delete of the browsers cache.

Comment: True, but the same `.blur()` functionality can be applied to any element in most modern browsers. A quick AJAX routine can POST the new content to the server :)